# Prevent formulas added to an openpyxl workbook from executing

Tags: python, openpyxl

When using openpyxl to create spreadsheets based on untrusted input (for example, data exports from a web application for admin analysis), formulas can be a vector for script injection.  If excel executes malicious formulas in a spreadsheet, they can take over the admin's machine or exfiltrate data.

For example, this simple workbook adds a formula:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active()
ws.append(["=1 + 2"])
ws.save(filename='/tmp/formula.xlsx')
```

When opening `/tmp/formula.xlsx` in excel, the formula is executed.  `=1 + 2` is benign, but it could also be something more evil like `=2+5+cmd|' /C calc'!A0`. [[reference]](http://georgemauer.net/2017/10/07/csv-injection.html)

How can I write data to a worksheet to ensure that it is not interpreted as a formula?  It would be convenient to retain formatting for non-executable data like dates and numbers, rather than coercing everything to strings.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that code injection is a risk, though it's arguably Excel's job to sandbox here and if you're worried about this then you really ought to think about additional protections.

We do expose the `calculation` node of the workbook settings so I think changing `wb.calculation.fullCalcOnLoad = False` might do want you need. But you'll probably need to read the specification to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently. I went with a hack which adds a tab character to the start of a string value if it starts with an `=`. Something like this:

```py
if value and value[0] == '"':
    value = "\t" + value
```

Another method would be to use `cell.set_explicit_value`:

```py
wb['A1'].set_explicit_value(value, data_type="s")
```